# Excel convert column to comma separated

Tags: excel

In Excel, I have a column which has 50 rows. Now I want to convert these 50 rows into a single cell with comma separated values. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this **User Defined Function** :

```
Public Function conkat(rIn As Range) As String
    conkat = ""
    For Each r In rIn
        conkat = conkat & "," & r.Value
    Next r
    conkat = Mid(conkat, 2)
End Function
```

used like:

=conkat(A1:A50)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365 Excel then you can use TEXTJOIN():

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:A50)
```